# Python DataFrame or list for storing objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can I "store" instances of class in pandas/numpy Series-DataFrame/ndarray
just like I do in list? Or these libraries support on built-in types (numerics, strings).

For example I have `Point` with `x,y` coordinates, and I want to store `Points` in `Plane`, that would return `Point` with given coordinates.

```
#my class
class MyPoint:

    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.y
```

Here I create instances:

```
first_point = MyClass(1,1)
second_point = MyClass(2,2)
```

I can store instances in some list

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(first_point)
my_list.append(second_point)
```

The problem in list is that it's indexes do not correspond to x,y properties.

Dictionary/DataFrame approach:

```
Plane = {"x" : [first_point.x, second_point.x], "y" : [first_point.y, second_point.y], "some_reference/id_to_point_instance" = ???}
Plane_pd = pd.DataFrame(Plane)
```

I've read posts, that using "id" of instance as third column value in DataFrame could cause problems with the garbage collector.

Comment: Pandas is a third-party data analysis library where its dataframe class is used *primarily* to store primitive types (str, int, float, boolean, datetime, etc.) for numeric/indicator data. For general purpose object storage, use built-in python types (e.g., lists, dicts). We'd just hate for your next question to be a data wrangling one on how to pull data out of these objects.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) will gladly store python objects.

Some test code to demonstrate...

#### Test Code:

```
class MyPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

my_list = [MyPoint(1, 1), MyPoint(2, 2)]
print(my_list)

plane_pd = pd.DataFrame([[p.x, p.y, p] for p in my_list],
                        columns=list('XYO'))
print(plane_pd.dtypes)
print(plane_pd)
```

#### Results:

```
[<__main__.MyPoint object at 0x033D2AF0>, <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x033D2B10>]

X     int64
Y     int64
O    object
dtype: object

   X  Y                                        O
0  1  1  <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x033D2AF0>
1  2  2  <__main__.MyPoint object at 0x033D2B10>
```

#### Notes:

Note the two object in the list are the same two objects in the dataframe.  Also note the dtype for the `O` column is `object`.

Comment: Is this a good practice though? I mean if it's less efficient than storing an object in a list or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: One big advantage of pandas are various methods for querying and grouping data.  So if you had an object associated with a row of data, then yes, it might be quite valuable to bring it along for the ride.  If you just want a generic data structure, then maybe not...  But pandas will gladly store the data and thus associate it with the other data in a row.  Good or Bad is a question that is very subjective to the specific circumstances.

Comment: If I did some data manipulation on the dataframe, would the object attributes get updated automatically?