# Combine pandas with object oriented programming

Tags: python, pandas, oop, design-patterns, pydantic

In my scientific career, the typical use case of **data analysis** seemed to be a perfect fit for `functional programming` and I never felt the need to define classes or use `OOP` techniques.

In Python I have been using `pandas` for tabular data. In a recent project however, I pushed `tree data` into pandas dataframes. The solution grew in complexity and became hard and time consuming to maintain. I ended up being the only person that understood how the code works and when I switched the job, the handover turned out to be almost impossible.

I got into **OOP** and **design patterns** and I want to apply that to further work in my new role as PO for a large scale data crunching algorithm with 200k+ lines of code.
I believe that OOP would allow to:

1. Define classes that represent objects that really exist in my model
2. Be more flexible to frequent changes in the data format, using the **adapter pattern**
3. Provide automated documentation by generating `uml` `class diagrams` using `doxygen`
4. Have data validation and type security using `pydantic`
5. Come handy if we defined threads and parallelize them

However I struggle with getting the OOP paradigm work. Maybe I am impacted by my long experience in functional programming and limited experience in OOP. **Or is OOP not the right solution for this particular case?**

Until now the team was pressing every piece of data into tables, because exporting into DBs (without relationships between tables) or **csv** files is so *convenient*. But a hierarchical tree structure would be a better fit. The input data comes as tables.

I could import that into a dataframe, apply some performant `pandas` df operations, that are more efficient than anything I could come up with.

On the other side, I see the effort it takes to come up with a class structure that works, only to instantiate objects, with attributes that are stored in dataframe cells. And then somehow looping over the instances?

My latest idea was to define objects, but store their attributes in a dataframe.

I have found that interesting question:
[Python DataFrame or list for storing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219023/python-dataframe-or-list-for-storing-objects)

Is that a good practice? Or is `pandas` not the right tool for OOP?
Could I actually manipulate the dataframe and automatically update to objects? Would this even make sense?

At least now, for the first time, I have not just started coding but try to structure the approach, before the code grows in a big mess.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and it's intrinsic to a problem that almost everyone involved in data and python has had sometime in his career.

**Short answer**: Use what it works for you.

**Long answer**: OOP and FOP are both good solutions to work with pandas dataframes. In this case, you want to create a class for your dataframe, that has some methods which are going to act like the functions you are using in your FOP. Doing this, you can control within a single object what you do and how the dataframe is designed. This can be achieved too with functional programming, just passing the dataframe into a data pipeline with functions that manipulate and transform the dataframe.